# Adding additional info for initial state of Drizzle

Tags: solidity, truffle, react, drizzle

How do I add extra content to the initial state of drizzle? I want to keep some local information that is not dependant on the blockchain. Should I keep a seperate redux store for that or is there a way to integrate this with drizzle?

Comment: What extra information you want to add? And could you give a code snippet?